# How to check for the latest version of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to know what is the last version of Minecraft with Download?Is there a site or something like?

Comment: By last do you mean the latest version? Are you including snapshots, or just release builds?

Comment: Yes, exactly.@colorfusion

Comment: Are you using the official minecraft launcher or the cracked?

Comment: @DaQuijibo I haven't Minecraft, I'm looking for a way to install Minecraft on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

From the Minecraft launcher, you can click <kbd>Edit Profile</kbd> near the bottom left to bring up the "Profile Editor":

[image: Profile editor]

You should see a drop-down labeled `Use version:`, which defaults to `Use Latest Version`. If you click this, you'll get a list of versions, with the top one being the most recent.

---

If you want to include snapshots, you can tick `Enable experimental development versions ("snapshots")`, and the same drop-down will now include snapshots:

[image: Drop-down with snapshots]

Answer (score 1):

Click edit profile. Then click versions. Then click use latest version. Click save profile and your all clear. Make sure to save your Profile or else all the work you did will be lost. :(